# Solving equation by mathematica and Finding value of b in an equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, integral-equations, mathematica-online, wave-equation

I have an equation and I have tried solving it to find values of b but it doesn't give me any values

The equation that I have tried to solve is :

```
 ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a+b)/(1-b)]]-(Vi/h)*Integrate[Sqrt[(1+(x/h)^2)^(-1)],{x,(h/2)*Log[b],0}]+(Pi/4)+m*Pi=0
```

I tried on it as following:

```
a = 0; m = 0; c = 0.98; d = c - (a*(1 - c));
bValue = Table[FindRoot[ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a+b)/(1-b)]]-(Vi/h)*Integrate[Sqrt[(1+(x/h)^2)^(-1)],{x,(h/2)*Log[b],0}]+(Pi/4)+m*Pi,{b,0.5}], {Vi, 0.8, 5.0, 0.1}];
bValues = Re[b /. bValue]
bValuesList = Transpose[{Join[{b}, bValues]}]
bGrid = Grid[bValuesList, Frame -> All]
vValues = Table[i, {i, 0, 20, 0.1}]
vValuesList = Transpose[{Join[{V}, vValues]}]
vGrid = Grid[vValuesList, Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Evaluate the integral once

```
int = Assuming[0 < b < 1,
  Integrate[Sqrt[(1 + (x/h)^2)^(-1)], {x, (h/2)*Log[b], 0}]]

(* -h ArcSinh[Log[b]/2] *)

a = 0; m = 0; c = 98/100; d = c - (a*(1 - c));

expr[Vi_, b_] = ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a + b)/(1 - b)]] -
   (Vi/h)*int + (Pi/4) + m*Pi;

root[Vi_?NumericQ] :=
 NSolveValues[{expr[Vi, b] == 0, 0 < b < 1}, b][[1]]
```

**EDIT:** Or use

```
root[Vi_?NumericQ] := b /. 
 FindRoot[expr[Vi, b] == 0, {b, 0.3}]

viList = {4/5, 2, 4, 8};

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[expr[Vi, b],
    StringForm["Vi = ``", Vi]], {Vi, viList}],
 {b, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {b, HoldForm@expr[Vi, b]},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[pt = {root[#], 0}], pt[[1]]] & /@ viList},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[viList, LegendLabel -> Vi],
   {.7, .3}]]
```

[image]

```
step = 0.4; (* change to desired granularity *)

Grid[
 Prepend[
  Table[{Vi, root[Vi]}, {Vi, 0.8, 8, step}],
  {Vi, b}],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your way to solve the equation but it does not give me as you have written here

Comment: If you copy and pasted my code and it didn't work, there must be a difference with Mma versions, presumably with `NSolveValues`. I used v13.1, what version are you using?

Comment: yes i think the problem on NSolveValues , the version is 11.2

Comment: Then use `root[Vi_?NumericQ] := b /. FindRoot[expr[Vi, b] == 0, {b, 0.3}]`

Comment: ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a+b)/(1-b)]]-(Vi/h)*Integrate[Sqrt[(1+(x/h)^2)^(-1)-b],{x,(h/2)*Log[b],0}]+(Pi/4)+m*Pi=0 .... there is an eddit in the equation can you see it please?!

Comment: Changing the equation does not fundamentally change the question. The approaches given in the answers still apply. So what have you tried and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: when i apply the code for the new equation it does not give me any solution and give an error

Comment: So post a new question, show the exact code you are using, and explain what specific errors that you are getting.

Comment: I have posted the question

Answer (score 3):

Change the integration variable `x to xdh=x/h` , in this way parameter `h` dissappears

```
eq = ArcTan[1/d*Sqrt[(a + b)/(1 - b)]] - (Vi/h)*Integrate[Sqrt[(1 + (xdh)^2)^(-1)], {xdh,(1/2)*Log[b], 0}] h + (Pi/4) +m*Pi
```

`ConturPlot` shows possible real solutions `{Vi,b}`

```
pic=ContourPlot[0 == eq, {Vi, .8, 5}, {b, 0.0, .6}, FrameLabel -> {Vi, b}]
```

[image]

List of solutions found:

```
pic[[1, 1]][[1]]
(*{{0.8, 0.0416416},{0.804065,0.0422764}, 
{0.807732,0.0428571}, {0.8375,0.0477974}, 
{0.838872, 0.0480182},...}*)
```

Alternatively try direct solution `NSolve`

```
sol[Vi_] := {Vi, b} /. NSolve[{0 ==eq[[1]], 0 < b < 1}, b][[1]]   
Table[sol[Vi], {Vi, .8, 5, .1}]
```

Comment: why when i put a=100 it doesn't give me any result ?!

Comment: Perhaps no real solution exists for `a==100`. Try to visualize with `Plot3D[eq, {b, 0, 1}, {Vi, 0.8, 5}]`

Comment: I have used Plot3D before but it does  not work, if it is does not have real solution and just imaginary ones how i can get the figure for the real part of the solutions?!

Comment: `Plot3D[eq,...]` shows a surface depending on b,Vi. If surface only shows points `<0` there is no real solution!

Comment: Restart your kernel and evaluate my code. Now `Plot3D[eq, {b, 0, 1}, {Vi, 0.8, 5}]` should show a surface?

Comment: yes yes it give me a surface and it give me points >0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138612/discussion-between-a-j-h-and-ulrich-neumann).